# intersection of linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

[Output showing the wrong intersection of List 1 and List 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNlFI.png)I am writing a function for the intersection of two linked lists but somehow I keep getting the wrong output.The idea is to initialize an empty list and to traverse through list 1 by using Find function to check if it intersects with list 2.If it does, then it is added to the list 4 (answer) which is returned after traversing through the list 1.

Here is the function, as well as the supporting functions it calls:

```
List Intersection(List L1, List L2) {
    List L4 = MakeEmpty(NULL);
    Position A = First(L1);
    Position B = First(L2); 
    Position C = Header(L4);
    while(A != NULL){
        if(Find(A->Element, L2) != NULL) {  
            Insert(A->Element, L4, C);
            A = A->Next;
            C = C->Next;
        } else {
            A = A->Next;
        }
    }
    return L4;
}

Position Find( ElementType X, List L ) {
    Position P = L->Next;
    while( P != NULL && P->Element != X )
        P = P->Next;
    return P;
}

void Insert( ElementType X, List L, Position P ) {
    Position TmpCell = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    // [check for null]
    TmpCell->Element = X;
    TmpCell->Next = P->Next;
    P->Next = TmpCell;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks right to me, provided that your linked-list implementation behaves the way that your code is assuming. Obviously we can't check whether that's the case, though.

Comment: I also can't figure out what is going wrong.My output prints the intersection correctly but then it inserts the missing characters from list 2 at the beginning as well even though I have no such statement.

Comment: Why the parameter `List L` is never used in the function `Insert()`. What is the difference between `Position pNode = First(pList);` and `Position pNode = Header(pList);`

Comment: @J.Piquard: Judging from the assumptions that Zero_Cool's code is making, it appears that each list starts with a dummy "header" node; if so, then `Header` returns that node, while `First` returns its successor, which is the first node with actual data (or is `NULL`, if the list is empty).

Comment: @ruakh, it is also now my conclusion. Another unclear point is the presence of a `Position Next` parameter in the structure of the list => detected by the `Position P = L->Next;` in the function `Find()` !!!

Comment: @J.Piquard: My *guess* would be that `List` and `Position` are both (equivalent) typedefs for `Node *`, and that `Header` actually just returns its argument. Stack Overflow questions have given me a lot of practice in making guesses about code I can't see. :-)